# Accessing static object from custom View class in Android

Tags: android, arrays, static, android-view, android-inflate

I have a view class `IntroScreen`, which is inflated in my xml layout.
Inflation works great until I try to access a static `String[]` element
defined inside my `onCreate` method. Somehow it gives me a `NullPointerException` even though the call to inflate my `IntroScreen` view happens after I initialize my `String[]` object. Here's some code:

```
//class MainActivity which holds onCreate()
static String[] stringArray;

//inside onCreate

stringArray = new String[20];
stringArray[0] = "the world";
stringArray[1] = "is round";

//a few lines down the code... still inside onCreate()
intro = (IntroScreen)this.findViewById(R.id.hereintro);

//inside my IntroScreen which extends view
//constructors are as follows:
public IntroScreen(Context c){
    super(c);
}

public IntroScreen(Context c, AttributeSet a){
 super(c, a);
 boolean b = false;

 if(MainActivity.stringArray[0].equals("the world"))b = true; //problem here
 //above line of code gives null pointer exception
} 

//inside onDraw()
//need more calls to MainActivity.stringArray in order to create custom view
//but calls won't work at all
```

My question is how can I access this static String[] array? I can't pass
it to my IntroScreen view since it's inflated via xml in the line of code

```
intro = (IntroScreen)this.findViewById(R.id.hereintro);
```

Any ideas of suggestions,

many thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of the static String array? Is it really the same for all instances of your activity?

Comment: Instead of writing comments like `//inside onCreate()`, just write the actual declaration of `onCreate()`. The same goes for the class.

Comment: I created a class (not an inner class) need to access static String[] array defined inside MainActivity class. Not all variables are created this way. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: That does not seem like a good reason to create a `static` variable to me. I only create `static` variables when every instance of a class must share the same value. There are several other ways to share variables between classes. For instance, you can pass the variable as a parameter to the constructor of the other class or to a method.

Comment: I know we can do these things, but the problem is that the view is inflated via xml layouts. So, I cant really create it such as customView = new IntroScreen(getApplicationContext(), variableToPassAsParameter)..this is why I have to define it as static. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: you can add a setter method to your view class or a getter to your activity. You do not **have** to make the variable static

Comment: can you explain how to to this? Anyways won't the setter / getter methods need to have access to the variable inside my MainActivity? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Let's back up just a little. It appears that your static variable is an array of String constants. Do the values of these change? What is the purpose of these? Are they displayed somewhere in your UI?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `IntroScreen` is called before `onCreate()` gets called, so your array is not yet initialized. Simply make sure to initialize it before inflating your activity.

Comment: I did initialized my array before setContentView call , but It still gives me the NulPointerException @DimitryBrant

Comment: fixed it... Silly mistake of mine. I was calling another String[] array in my code which was initialized way after setcontentview.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

pass that string array parameter to `public IntroScreen(Context c, AttributeSet a)`